# Get Authenticated User ID in Hook Cron?

Tags: 7, hooks, cron

I have been trying to get the current authenticated user ID in Hook_cron() function.

But Its showing only the anonymous user, though the current user is an authenticated user.

How Could I get the current authenticated user in hook_cron()

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing - cron always runs as the anonymous user.

This is forced by the [`drupal_cron_run()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_cron_run/7.x) function in Drupal 7:

```
// Force the current user to anonymous to ensure consistent permissions on
// cron runs.
$original_user = $GLOBALS['user'];
$GLOBALS['user'] = drupal_anonymous_user();
```

and [`Cron::run`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Cron.php/function/Cron%3A%3Arun/8.5.x) in Drupal 8:

```
// Force the current user to anonymous to ensure consistent permissions on
// cron runs.
$this->accountSwitcher
  ->switchTo(new AnonymousUserSession());
```